# Qt: 'Q3DScatter' not recognized even though it is included

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show a 3DScatter graph in my main window.

In my *mainwindow.h* i have included `#include <Q3DScatter>` but when entering `3DScatter scatterGraph;` in the *public:* section of the MainWindow class i get this error message:

```
error: unknown type name 'Q3DScatter'
```

Here is what I've already checked:

- In the Qt Maintenance Tool the 'Qt Data Visualization' module is already installed
- There are no errors for `#include <Q3DScatter>`
- When going to *Tools -> Locate* and entering 'Q3DScatter' it finds both `Q3DScatter` and `q3dscatter.h`
- In `q3dscatter.h` exists classes named `Q3DScatterPrivate` and `Q3DScatter`
- In the `.pro` file the first line is `QT       += core gui datavisualization`

What am I doing wrong? The module seems to exist but why can't I create the `Q3DScatter scatterGraph`?

EDIT:
This is the entire error message from the Compile Output:

```
In file included from ../MandelbulbUI/main.cpp:1:0:
../MandelbulbUI/mainwindow.h:26:5: error: ‘Q3DScatter’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘QDate’?
     Q3DScatter scatterGraph;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     QDate
In file included from ../MandelbulbUI/mainwindow.cpp:1:0:
../MandelbulbUI/mainwindow.h:26:5: error: ‘Q3DScatter’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘QDate’?
     Q3DScatter scatterGraph;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     QDate
In file included from moc_mainwindow.cpp:9:0:
../MandelbulbUI/mainwindow.h:26:5: error: ‘Q3DScatter’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘QDate’?
     Q3DScatter scatterGraph;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     QDate
Makefile:1598: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1817: recipe for target 'moc_mainwindow.o' failed
make: *** [moc_mainwindow.o] Error 1
Makefile:1805: recipe for target 'mainwindow.o' failed
make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 1
17:30:54: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project MandelbulbUI (kit: Desktop Qt 5.12.7 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your IDE complaining incorrectly? What is the *complete* compiler error message (if any) when you compile your program?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message from the compiler.

Comment: Are you sure `Q3DScatter` etc. aren't declared under their own namespace?

Comment: I am not sure. Honestly I don't even really know what that means and why it would be necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the headers suggests that `Q3DScatter` is declared under the namespace `QtDataVisualization`.  That being the case you need to use...

```
QtDataVisualization::Q3DScatter scatterGraph;
```